# sed to replace text url to html url

Tags: sed, html, url

I have a bunch of URL in a text file.
As Firefox seems unable to load these URL directly, I must convert them to HTML.

Trying with `sed` doesn't work:

```
sed -e 's/^(.*)$/<a href="\1">\1<\/a><br>/g' myfile.txt
```

Error message returned (translated, it may not look exactly so on english systems):

```
sed: -e expression n°1, char 33: invalid reference \1 in right side of the command `s'
```

I simply wonder why?

URLs are like so:

```
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378496/sed-to-replace-text-url-to-html-url
```

some may contain these char: % & / \ _ - = :

And it seems I got a "linebreak" char at the end of the line, before the real line break, so included in the .* statement. It should be because the file was created under a Windows environment.

Comment: please add a sample of URLs you have and its HTML format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to group parts of an regex, either use `\(\)` or use extended regular expression syntax by providing the `-E` option to `sed`.

In your case it's not needed at all, as for the whole match you can use `&` in the replacement:

```
sed 's/.*/<a href="&"><\/a><br>/' myfile.txt
```

Note that you can also drop the `^` and `$` as the greedy `*` makes the match cover the whole line.

Comment: `g` is also not needed because you've already selected the whole line with `.*` and if by any chance the URL's are separated by space rather than new lines which `g` in your code assumes, this code will not work as you have replaced the whole line without considering space as a delimiter.

Comment: it seems to work except for the extra newlines.

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut Thank you, removed the `g`. s.k., what extra newlines? This is not supposed to add newlines. If your file has empty lines, you may drop them with `sed -n 's/^http.*/<a href="&"><\/a><br>/p' myfile.txt`, ignoring lines that don't start with `http`

Comment: (one `&` missing: ....`/<a href="&">&<\/a><br>/` )

Answer (score -1):

You are using `/` in your sed expression as a separator, capturing text with `/`, so it fails.

Try `'s@^(.*)$@<a href="\1">\1<\/a><br>@g'`, assuming there are no mailto links you want to convert ;-)

You could also use `'s!^(.*)$!<a href="\1">\1<\/a><br>!g'`

Comment: No, the slash is correctly escaped by the backslash. This was not the cause of the problem.