# how to convert plaintext to html with clickable links

Tags: text-processing, html, url

how can i convert plaintext files containing a bunch of urls to html with clickable links? preferably on the command line.

every once in a while i end up with a plaintext file containing a bunch of urls. often one url per line. maybe some empty lines in between. sometimes with some text. sometimes even text and url in one line.

```
$ cat foo.txt 
some links
https://stackoverflow.com/
https://superuser.com/
https://askubuntu.com/

best? https://unix.stackexchange.com/
```

the files are generated by humans so i cannot just configure the source to output well formatted files.

if there are only couple of urls then i can copy them by hand. or `cat` in gnome terminal (which makes urls clickable) and click on the links. i can even `cat foo.txt | xargs firefox`.

but if they are mixed with text or if there are too many links then all that is no longer feasible.

i would like to not start to try to parse urls using regex: [sed to replace text url to html url](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378496/sed-to-replace-text-url-to-html-url)

Answer (score 2):

[pandoc](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) to the rescue

```
pandoc -f markdown+autolink_bare_uris+hard_line_breaks foo.txt > foo.html
```

`autolink_bare_uris` makes links clickable even when not markdown formatted as link

`hard_line_breaks` treats every newline as line break

example:

```
$ cat foo.txt 
some links
https://stackoverflow.com/
https://superuser.com/
https://askubuntu.com/

best? https://unix.stackexchange.com/

$ pandoc -f markdown+autolink_bare_uris+hard_line_breaks foo.txt
<p>some links<br />
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" class="uri">https://stackoverflow.com/</a><br />
<a href="https://superuser.com/" class="uri">https://superuser.com/</a><br />
<a href="https://askubuntu.com/" class="uri">https://askubuntu.com/</a></p>
<p>best? <a href="https://unix.stackexchange.com/" class="uri">https://unix.stackexchange.com/</a></p>
```

---

alternative to pandoc: [md4c](https://github.com/mity/md4c)

not as "heavy" as pandoc. it is a dependency of qt5-base (in archlinux) so you might have this installed already on your system.

```
$ md2html --fpermissive-url-autolinks foo.txt 
<p>some links
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">https://stackoverflow.com/</a>
<a href="https://superuser.com/">https://superuser.com/</a>
<a href="https://askubuntu.com/">https://askubuntu.com/</a></p>
<p>best? <a href="https://unix.stackexchange.com/">https://unix.stackexchange.com/</a></p>
```

there seem to be no option to treat every newline as line break. that means the urls without empty lines between them will be clumped together in one paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the `foo.txt` example above with [Featherpad](https://github.com/tsujan/FeatherPad) editor they will display as clickable links.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).